# Same tables in multiple Schemas in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a single mysql server running with multiple dbs that have some tables that are exactly the same (don't ask, I inherited this project):

DB01, DB02 and DB03 have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

They also have many other tables that are the same amongst them, and, in addition DB01, DB02 and DB03 have other tables that are exclusive to them.

Is it possible to use a single model/service layer for the table structure above so that I can query each table individually using Hibernate?

What I have tried is setting up an abstract super class (using @MappedSuperclass), but that requires having lots of files that inherit this class with the only difference being the @Table(name = "DB01.table1"), @Table(name = "DB02.table1")... reference.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define multiple DataSources and swap them on fly. No need to multiply classes.

E.g. [this approach](http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/multiple_db_with_single_sessionfactory) is based on `org.springframework.aop.target.HotSwappableTargetSource`